# Delete docker images from private registry

Tags: docker, containers, devops

I need to delete some unused images from a private registry, but I’m having some difficulty enabling the delete option in the docker-compose file to start the container.

Already set the environment variable REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED to the following values but none work.

`true`
`"true"`
`1`
`"yes"`

After restarting the container I checked the /etc/docker/registry/config.yml and the option to delete wasn't there, so I set manually set the configuration inside the container to:

`storage: delete: enabled: true` 
But after tried to delete using curl returned the following message:

```
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{"errors":[{"code":"UNSUPPORTED","message":"The operation is unsupported."}]}
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
 Connection #0 to host left intact
```

I looked for solutions in the registry documentation and tried some posted in here but they didn’t work. Someone knows what I can do? The registry version is 2.7.1

Comment: You will want to add the `curl` command that you tried

Comment: Can you mark this post as solved? I was able to delete without use curl, just with the garbage collector I free 105gb of unused/obsolet images.

Comment: You can write an answer to the post and then 24h later mark it as the solution.